# javafx2.2 making a scrollbar with transparent background

Tags: css, background, scrollbar, javafx, skinning

I am trying to make a scrollpane with a scrollbar that has transparent (or at least solid)  background by styling it with css in javafx 2.2.3.

```
.scroll-pane .track{-fx-opacity: 0;}
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar{-fx-base: transparent;}
```

Strangely, the code above makes scrollbar black. Giving -fx-base any value with alfa does that.

Background-color has no efect at all...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a [sample](https://gist.github.com/2838292) which displays a scroll bar with a transparent background.

The sample includes some extra program logic to only show visual feedback on the scrollbar when the user hovers over the scrollbar - you may or may not need that.

The css related to the scrollbar in the sample is:

```
.address .scroll-pane {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.address .scroll-bar .increment-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.address .scroll-bar .decrement-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.address .scroll-bar:vertical {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.address .scroll-bar:vertical .track-background {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.address .scroll-bar:vertical .track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.address .hide-thumb .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Where the scroll bar being made transparent has the additional custom style class of address assigned to it.

I determined the css to use by studying the scroll-bar section of the default JavaFX 2.2 css stylesheet [caspian.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css).

Output of the sample is:

[image: The Gettysburg address]

Comment: thank You, although I couldn't achieve the same result with `visibility: hidden;`, `-fx-opacity: 0;` worked :)